# IndexError: string index out of range doesn't make sense

Tags: python, index-error

I have a problem that i can't explain, I'm making a program to find the "longest common prefix" and I got an error `IndexError: string index out of range.`

I noticed that changing the order on an if statement was the solution, but that doesn't make sense for me.

This line was:

```
if default[j] == list[i][j] and j < len(default):
```

The solution to the problem is:

```
    if j < len(default) and default[j] == list[i][j]:
```

Why does this happen, isn't it the same? Am I blind?

This is the code with the error:

```
list=["hola", "holo", "holi"]
default=list[0]

for i in range(1, len(list)):
    temp=""
    if len(default)==0:
        break;

    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        if default[j] == list[i][j] and j < len(default):
            temp+=default[j]
        else:
            break

    default=temp
print(default)
```

Comment: The condition checking happens from left to right. So when j becomes larger than defaults size it will throw. But if the length check is made first then the condition fails right there, and doesn't go any further.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I didn't think that. Thank you so much, guys

Answer (score 0):

Order matter when using `and` operator.

```py
a and b
```

If a is true then only b is checked. It doesn't matter if b consist of an error (except syntax error).

Answer (score 0):

The two statements are not the same.

if we have a condition statement

```
if Condtion1 and Condetion2:
```

Conditon2 will be checked if and only if Condtion1 is True.

Let us examine the folowing short examples, and it will be clear:

```
a=10
b=0
if b!=0 and a/b>3:
   print('Do Something')
else:
   print('ok')
```

The output will be `ok`

But, if we reorder the condtions in if statement `if a/b>3 and b!=0:`

```
a=10
b=0
if a/b>3 and b!=0:
   print('Do Something')
else:
   print('ok')
```

The later code give error `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`, where, a/b was examined first and the fact the b is equal to 0.

But, in the first code, the conditon b!=0 was examined first, and gives `False`, so the second condition `a/b>3` was not processed.

So, the two statements are not the same.